# Is there an error in the package program and main program?

Tags: java, package

I have written a package program and main program. The program doesnt run in cmd. I also think that programs are correct, please correct me if I'm wrong. Also please help me in the execution of the package program and the main program. Please execuse me if the code looks stupid or doesnt make sense, im learning Java slowly. Im trying to find the average marks of 10 students in 5 subjects using packages. Package code:

```
package average;

public class avg {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        double mark1[] = {1, 10, 7, 5, 6};
        double mark2[] = {2, 9, 8, 4, 7};
        double mark3[] = {3, 8, 9, 3, 2};
        double mark4[] = {4, 7, 11, 4, 3};
        double mark5[] = {5, 6, 3, 5, 9};
        double mark6[] = {6, 5, 5, 5, 6};
        double mark7[] = {7, 4, 3, 7, 2};
        double mark8[] = {8, 3, 8, 9, 6};
        double mark9[] = {9, 2, 1, 7, 4};
        double mark0[] = {10, 1, 10, 9, 10};
        double result1 = 0;
        double result2 = 0;
        double result3 = 0;
        double result4 = 0;
        double result5 = 0;
        double result6 = 0;
        double result7 = 0;
        double result8 = 0;
        double result9 = 0;
        double result0 = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            result1 = result1 + mark1[i];
            result2 = result2 + mark2[i];
            result3 = result3 + mark3[i];
            result4 = result4 + mark4[i];
            result5 = result5 + mark5[i];
            result6 = result6 + mark6[i];
            result7 = result7 + mark7[i];
            result8 = result8 + mark8[i];
            result9 = result9 + mark9[i];
            result0 = result0 + mark0[i];
        }
    }
}
```

Main program:

```
import average.avg;
public class ex5A{
    public static void main(String []args){

        System.out.println("The average marks for student 1 is " +result1/5);
        System.out.println("The average marks for student 2 is " +result2/5);
        System.out.println("The average marks for student 3 is " +result3/5);
        System.out.println("The average marks for student 4 is " +result4/5);
        System.out.println("The average marks for student 5 is " +result5/5);
        System.out.println("The average marks for student 6 is " +result6/5);
        System.out.println("The average marks for student 7 is " +result7/5);
        System.out.println("The average marks for student 8 is " +result8/5);
        System.out.println("The average marks for student 9 is " +result9/5);
        System.out.println("The average marks for student 10 is " +result0/5);

    }    
}
```

The errors that I have found has been added as a code below:

```
    symbol:   variable result5
  location: class ex5A
ex5A.java:12: error: cannot find symbol
        System.out.println("The average marks for student 6 is " +result6/5);
                                                                  ^
  symbol:   variable result6
  location: class ex5A
ex5A.java:13: error: cannot find symbol
        System.out.println("The average marks for student 7 is " +result7/5);
                                                                  ^
  symbol:   variable result7
  location: class ex5A
ex5A.java:14: error: cannot find symbol
        System.out.println("The average marks for student 8 is " +result8/5);
                                                                  ^
  symbol:   variable result8
  location: class ex5A
ex5A.java:15: error: cannot find symbol
        System.out.println("The average marks for student 9 is " +result9/5);
                                                                  ^
  symbol:   variable result9
  location: class ex5A
ex5A.java:16: error: cannot find symbol
        System.out.println("The average marks for student 10 is " +result0/5);
                                                                   ^
  symbol:   variable result0
  location: class ex5A
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Are you trying to access the variables from one class in another? Because currently they're not in the same scope, `ex5A` has no reference to `avg`.

Comment: Yes, I'm trying to access them. How do I make them in the same scope?

Comment: Please don't post images of code or errors. See [ask].

Comment: Local variables are accessible only within the block in which they're defined. You can also store variables as class or instance fields, and ideally access them through methods. That said, maybe what you really want is to *return* an average from a function that accepts an array as a parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Java apps usually have only one main method. You should join these pieces of code in one main method and then try to execute.

I'd recommend you start learning Java with [java docs tutorials](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/)
It is the best way for learning Java for complete beginners.